# Command to change volume

Tags: volume-control

This works in 16.04 but not in 18.04.

Is there a fix?

```
 amixer -D pulse sset Master 30%
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine in my Ubuntu 18.04.

try to use the command alsamixer.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 100%
```

[image: amixer -D pulse sset Master 100%]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: @varshneydevansh Your post is exactly what I had. :-)